# How do I change the color of GTK's "Dropdown"?

Tags: gtk, gtk2

I am just trying to tweak my GTK Theme to have a dark background color and light foreground color for Menu, Panel, Menu Bar.

However, I have a problem with "Dropdowns" which has a dark background color, and a dark background!

It seems to be taking the background of the `clearlooks-menu` and foreground of the `clearlooks-default` which seems to be an incorrect combination. How do I correct this?

[image: GTK Dropdown]

I have been checking the [Wiki](https://wiki.gnome.org/Attic/GnomeArt/Tutorials/GtkThemes/GtkList) but it is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with `widget_class "*.<GtkComboBox>.<GtkCellView>"`

In my case the below setting solved the issue:

```
widget_class "*.<GtkComboBox>.<GtkCellView>"   style "clearlooks-text-is-fg-color-workaround"

style "clearlooks-menuitem-text-is-fg-color-workaround"
{
  text[NORMAL]        = "#ffffff"
  text[PRELIGHT]      = @selected_fg_color
  text[SELECTED]      = @selected_fg_color
  text[ACTIVE]        = @fg_color
  text[INSENSITIVE]   = darker (@bg_color)
}
```